# How do I install popper v2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, popper.js

Running the command:

`npm install popper.js --save`

will return the warning message:

`npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1`

what the is npm command for installing popper v2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm install @popperjs/core --save`

This was a little more straight-forward than I was expecting. The formatting differences between v1 and v2 definitely threw me off